# How to enable the Google Search sidebar?

Tags: google-search

I have saw the sidebar marked in the picture enabled in other people. How can I enable this for me?

[image]

**EDIT:** The bar doesn't appear at all, I mean, the "-" sign of the show/hide options doesn't appear. How can I make show this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

You need to go to the option **Interface Language** and set it to ***English***.

Answer (score 2):

Click "Web [+] Show options..."

[image]

If that doesn't work, switch locals to en-US or en-GB (If you prefer English...)

Comment: How can I switch locals to EN-US?

Comment: Add hl=en-US to the end of the URL as a param, like this: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en-US&q=test

Answer (score 2):

See the little "-" sign in the top part of the circle in your screenshot?  When you do a Google search, it'll be a "+" when the results are first returned.  Click the + and it expands to the side bar you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Press the "Show Options" button in the left corner.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google have a habit of gradually rolling out features to different locations.  If you aren't seeing show or hide on the results page then Google probably haven't decided to give you that feature.